# Is it possible to pass a String to an AUAudioUnit as a parameter

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiounit, avaudiounit

I am currently working on a `AUAudioUnit` (AUv3) which requires to load a file located in the Host app's bundle.

This would need to pass the file path (ie: string value) to the Audio Unit as parameter, but I couldn't see how to do this with `AUParameter` since it seems to only supports Float values (`AUValue`).

Does anyone know if it's possible ? and how ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

For basic of working with audio engine start with WWDC videos like [wwdc 502](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FlMaxen2eyw)
For sample code, you can find it here at [shlab](https://github.com/ooper-shlab/AVAEMixerSample-Swift)

Comment: Thanks @mehdi, but it doesn't really answer to my question regarding `AUAudioUnit` parameter allowed types

Answer (score 0):

An AUParameterGroups allows one to pass multiple parameters.  And one can encode pretty much anything in a large enough array of values.  A C string is just an array of bits.